# apt-get upgrade fails due to dependency issues

Tags: apt

I'm trying to upgrade and while doing so, I get the following:

```
devteam@hephaestusx:~/Projects$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libboost-python-dev : Depends: libboost-python1.46-dev but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
devteam@hephaestusx:~/Projects$ apt-get -f install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
devteam@hephaestusx:~/Projects$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libboost-python1.46-dev libboost1.46-dev
Suggested packages:
  libboost1.46-doc libboost-date-time1.46-dev libboost-filesystem1.46-dev libboost-graph1.46-dev libboost-iostreams1.46-dev
  libboost-math1.46-dev libboost-program-options1.46-dev libboost-random1.46-dev libboost-regex1.46-dev libboost-serialization1.46-dev
  libboost-signals1.46-dev libboost-system1.46-dev libboost-test1.46-dev libboost-thread1.46-dev libboost-wave1.46-dev doxygen default-jdk
  fop
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libboost-python1.46-dev libboost1.46-dev
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/8,151 kB of archives.
After this operation, 80.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 226442 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libboost1.46-dev (from .../libboost1.46-dev_1.46.1-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.46-dev_1.46.1-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/boost/aligned_storage.hpp', which is also in package libboost1.40-dev 1.40.0-6ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Unpacking libboost-python1.46-dev (from .../libboost-python1.46-dev_1.46.1-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libboost-python1.46-dev_1.46.1-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libboost_python-py26.a', which is also in package libboost-python1.40-dev 1.40.0-6ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.46-dev_1.46.1-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libboost-python1.46-dev_1.46.1-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any idea on how to remedy this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You currently have `libboost1.40-all-dev` from Maverick installed. Now you are trying to install `libboost1.46-dev` from Oneiric. It's similar for `libboost-python1.46-dev`.

That doesn't work, mixing packages from different versions of Ubuntu only works in very few special cases.

Try to remove the packages `libboost-python1.46-dev` and `libboost1.46-dev`.

Comment: I suppose I want to remove the Maverick install and install the Oneiric version.

Comment: Thank you very much!

`$ sudo aptitude remove libboost-python1.46-dev && sudo aptitude remove libboost1.46-dev`

Worked!

Answer (score 0):

Root privileges are needed for apt-get upgrade too, so:

> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade